# A good place to learn about Game Programming with Mathematical Vectors?

Tags: physics, mathematics, game-mechanics

I am looking for a place in the web where I can turn my current game development process into a vector based approach. I am sorry If this question has been asked once.

According to my google search analysis, few places I've found pretty interesting are Tony Pa's tutorials and Metanet. But, due to limited explanations, I found it little bit tough to implement. I could try out the same examples as provided there, but when I have to use it in my games, I am STUCK. I want to know about the dot products and cross product stuff, Its uses and detecting collisions and predicting collisions with these mathematical techniques.

Please, write down some links and a brief description of the link. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go: http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/

This is the first entry in a series of (4) blog posts about linear algebra pertaining to game development. It'll explain about dot products, cross products and transformations using matrices.

Comment: Nice entry level tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pure web site, but you can view some of the contents of Mathematics for 3D Game Programming & Computer Graphics at Google Books here: [Mathematics for 3D Game Programming & Computer Graphics](http://books.google.com/books?id=bfcLeqRUsm8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Mathematics+for+3D+Game+Programming+%26+Computer+Graphics&hl=en&ei=MdORTKncHpqK4ga177SfBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA).

This is a very good book and well worth purchasing if you don't find a website to suit your needs.